# X-FRAME_OPTION DENY NOT WORKING LARAVEL API

Tags: reactjs, laravel, rest, http, x-frame-options

I am sending response x-frame-option header from my laravel API to react-js frontend using middleware:

```
class SecureHeaders
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block');
        $response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

I have set this to all routes in my kernal however I am still able to set this in IFRAME.

Comment: can you show how you set this in your `Kernel.php`? Can you also check your browser network tab to ensure the response does have the header set?

Comment: I have set this here 
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\SecureHeaders::class
    ];
AND Yes it is showing in response header.

Comment: then make sure you haven't started your browser in some odd mode that ignores the frame options (or try in a different browser?) Maybe also share how you are testing this

Comment: I have tested it in different browsers still didnt work does it work with API or I have to do this in react js?

Comment: not sure I understand. APIs are generally not embedded in iframes, can you showus how you are using this

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe src="http://localhost:3000/" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

</body>
</html>